# How to translate symbols from latin to cyrillic

Tags: python, windows, unicode

developers! I want to make a program in python, which converts symbols from latin to cyrillic.
For example: "ghbdtn" to "привет", which means "hello" in russian. Does someone know any methods that can help me?

I've discovered some posts about this, but didn't find a solution. And also I tried using transliteration but it translates the word.(for example: "privet" to "привет")

Comment: The process is called [Cyrillization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillization), in case that helps you find resources on it.

Comment: Why "ghbdtn" instead of "privet"?

Comment: There are many different standards for converting between Latin and Cyrillic. And conversions will differ between languages. Are there specific languages that you are targetting? Are there specific transliteration schemas?

Comment: @dan04 I suspect the OP isn't looking a cyrillisation or transliteration solution. Given his example it may be converting from a simple cipher back to Russian.

Comment: @dan04 not sure he is looking for a cyrillisation/transliteration solution. Given the example it might be a simple cipher. Either way he needs to build his own mapping table.

Comment: In short, I want to convert latin symbol to cyrillic. In keyboard layout, key F is А in cyrillic, so if you switch to EN in your system and press key F it will trigger F , but if you switch to RU, and press the same key, it will trigger А

Comment: if you forgot to switch between this languages, i want to make my program automatically convert all symbols from latin to cyrillic

Comment: @Joseph, what are the target and source layouts you intend to support? For target is it the ЙЦУКЕН Russian layout only, or do you need to support macOS layout, etc? For source layout: QWERTY, AZERTY, QWERTZ, or other? Do you need support for non-alphabetic characters?

Comment: ive found a solution finally, thanks

Comment: @Joseph that's good, esp since there are a range of layouts that may need to be supported, just for English, you'd have US and British layouts. And the currency sign might be awkward to implement a mapping for.

Answer (score 1):

To convert Latin characters to Cyrillic characters in Python, you can use the unidecode library

```
from unidecode import unidecode
def latin_to_cyrillic(input_text):
    cyrillic_text = unidecode(input_text, 'ru')
    return cyrillic_text

input_text = 'ghbdtn'
output_text = latin_to_cyrillic(input_text)
print(output_text)  # Output: привет
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you're *actually* asking for is a conversion from the standard English QWERTY *keyboard* layout to the Russian [JCUKEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JCUKEN) layout.  This can be done by using a `dict` to map one layout to the other.

```py
def build_translation_dict():
    result = {}
    QWERTY = "qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm`,."
    JCUKEN = "йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьёбю"
    for (latin, cyrillic) in zip(QWERTY, JCUKEN):
        result[ord(latin)] = cyrillic
        # Handle letter case pairs
        if latin.islower():
            result[ord(latin.upper())] = cyrillic.upper()
    return result
TRANSLATION_DICT = build_translation_dict()
```

And then you can just use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to convert a specific string.

```py
>>> str.translate("ghbdtn", TRANSLATION_DICT)
'привет'
```

Comment: Missing one Russian letter.

Comment: @Andj: Which one?

Comment: `ё`. You don't specify which querty layout you are targetting. Assuming ANSI (US) or UK, then the backtick (`), not sure your rules would work for US extended, UK extended, Irish or various Canadian flavours of QWERTY.

Comment: @Andj: I see.  I've added `ё` to my code.  Other punctuation characters may also need to be added depending on your exact keyboard layout.

Comment: The inherit problem of mapping QWERTY to ЙЦУКЕН is that QWERTY is a family of related keyboard layouts where the A..Z keys are positioned the same, all other keys can vary. You have additional complication that some keys on QWERTY layouts are  deadkeys. More complications if you need to add non-QWERTY layouts as well. But assuming an ANSI layout rather than an ISO layout, and basic rather than extended layout, the code above works well. Although punctuation keys should be covered as well in a final solution.